# Overfull hbox warning with table that is set to linewidth

Tags: tables, macros, linewidth

The following command produces a table with two columns. No padding to the sides and a relative padding in between the columns. In sum, the width amounts to linewidth, or so I thought -  I still get an "Overfull hbox" warning. Can anyone help?

```
\newcommand{\gloss}[2]{
     \par
     \noindent
     \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.2\linewidth}@{\hspace{0.03\linewidth}}p{0.77\linewidth}@{}}
          \textbf{#1} & #2
     \end{tabular}
}

\gloss{test}{this is a test}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: The missing `%` at the end of lines add spaces to your macro

Comment: you have one space more than linewidth